# How to cite a yet to be published paper in a Resume

Tags: resume, job-search, research

I am the first author of a paper that was presented at [this conference](https://www.wirn2018.polito.it/program/):

The papers accepted at this conference undergo publication process in a [volume by Springer](https://www.springer.com/series/8767):

> All accepted
>   contributions will be published in a special volume printed by Springer and indexed by SCOPUS

The conference was held in May, and at the end of June we submitted our paper to the reviewers for the publication in the volume, and we are still waiting for their reply. My question is: how should I present all this in my resume? I would like to mention the volume too, and not just the conference, but I am not sure on the best way to do it.

Comment: Usually within a year from the conference, but there is no given date.

Comment: A resume targeted at academia or for the corporate world? In most fields presenting at an industry conference would be much more important than a publication so why do you also want to include publishing details?

Comment: For the corporate world, in particular I am looking for a job in machine learning or data science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how should I present all this in my resume?

In the Publications section of your resume, you note the title of the paper, indicate that it was presented at the conference, and write something like "Under review for publication in xxxx".